# Why gnome-terminal does not allow unlimited scrolling

Tags: scrolling, gnome-terminal

I am using Fedora 14. Gnome Terminal 2.32.0.

But there is no box for "unlimited scrolling". In fact, the number of lines I can scroll back is capped at 10,000. If I set it any higher, it will reset to 10,000.

Also, I went to gconf-editor, and found a key "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/scrollback_unlimited". I toggled this value, but still I am limited to 10,000 lines of scrollback.

I read online unlimited scrollback was introduced in Gnome Terminal 2.28.

Is there some sort of system-wide or security conf entry that I am not aware of? If so I can talk to the sysadmins to get that changed.

Comment: This may have been a regression or even an intentionally excluded feature in Fedora 14, I used for a while and seem to remember something about that. In 2010, the gnome-terminal team set the default to 10K: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=624195, and there were issues surrounding it after that as well. I believe the option was there in Fedora 12 and just confirmed it is there in 17.

Answer (score 3):

buffer space usually requires memory. Unlimited scroll back buffer is not a realistic expectation in my opinion in any terminal emulator. 
if you have to keep the scroll back history for everything you do, just run the command

```
# script
```

before you start your session and everything you do, keypresses, cat'ing of files, etc, will all go to the typescript file. This way you can search what you are looking for in this file.

also, I am quite curious why a 10K line buffer wouldn't be enough for anyone. If you are scrolling that much way back in screen history, you must not be doing something right. For me, I can get by with 300-400 lines at any given time.

Comment: Is 300–400 lines really enough for you in any given moment? Depending on what process you run, you may get output sequences that surpass that number of lines and that you still want to see all of.

Comment: Yes 300-400 lines are usually enough but my putty sessions are usually set to 1000 lines, although I can't recall anytime in the recent-enough past that I needed to scoll past 10-12 screens which is about 250-300 lines. Again, screen buffer is not your replacement for logging. If your logs are not helping you find what you need, consider changing your log parameters and the method you are searching them.

Comment: Is there any real danger to the unlimited setting? Like e.g. running out of memory?

Comment: It is dependent on your workstation, not the server you are connecting to. If you set it to unlimited (I am not even sure if there is such a setting) at some point, your terminal emulator will get sluggish, due to keeping track of what is in the scroll back buffer. As I have previously mentioned, I never needed anything beyond 10-12 screens ago, so I never configured my terminal with such absurd settings. My answer is just an educated guess.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty old question.

On recent gnome-terminals you can go to edit->profile preferences.
Then go to Scrolling tab and check the "Unlimited" checkbox

[image]

This example is from my Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME Terminal 3.6.2

Edit: 6 Dec 2023 for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Version 3.44.0 for GNOME 42

[image]